# Declaration of array inside struct fails sometimes

Tags: c, arrays, struct, segmentation-fault

What makes the following code fail on some Linux/gcc environments? I declare a struct and then create an "instance" of this struct. The problem is with an array, which should hold separate strings and be resizeable. Details:

```
typedef struct {
    char (*pointer)[256];
    int used;
    int size;
} Array;

Array *createArray(int start_size) {
    Array *array = malloc(sizeof( *array));
    array->used = 0;
    array->size = start_size;
    array->pointer = malloc(start_size * sizeof *array->pointer); // <--- here
    return array;
}
```

The line which uses uninitialized value(s) is marked with `<--` below (`strcpy`). 
`parse` function `append`s to the array using `append` function.

```
void append(Array *array, char* elem) {
    if (array->used >= array->size) {
        // expand table
        array->pointer = realloc(array->pointer, array->size * 2 * sizeof *array->pointer);
        array->size *= 2;
    }
    // append new arg
    strcpy(array->pointer[array->used] , elem); // <-- here
    array->used++;
}

Array *parse(char* command) {
    // split command by space and store each arg in array
    char *args_str;
    Array *args_list = createArray(DEFAULT_SIZE); // expandable array holding arguments
    args_str = strtok(command, " ");
    append(args_list, args_str);
    args_str = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

Valgrind shows, that there is an error on the line marked above with `<--- here` due to usage of uninitialized values, but the code works fine inside Valgrind and also on:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) 3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64, gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS 4.4.0-112-generic, gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6)
```

But fails on:

```
Linux kali 4.13.0-kali1-amd64, gcc version 7.2.0 (Debian 7.2.0-14)
```

throwing `SEGFAULT 11` immediately after first input to the program, which is after compiling process, it compiles ok on each of the environments.

Comment: The problem is in the code you *didn't* show.  Valgrind is telling you where the memory was allocated.  It also tells you where you used the uninitialized value that was allocated there.  Check out *that* line.

Comment: See [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I tried to make it MCVE, but I guess I focused too much on "minimal". I updated the code, highlighting problematic line.

Comment: You have: `Array *array = malloc(sizeof( *array));`.

    This probably isn't what you want to allocate -- you've given enough space for a pointer, not for the struct. Replace with:

    `Array *array = malloc(sizeof(array));`. 

It looks like you don't really understand what malloc does and how it works, since you make the same mistake when you malloc for `array->pointer`. And your array in the struct definition is unusual too -- you're telling it to allocate 256 pointers, not 256 characters.

Comment: @MattS no, `Array *array = malloc(sizeof( *array));` is correct. `sizeof *array` returns the number of bytes a `Array` object needs. `sizeof(array)` returns the number of  bytes a pointer to `Array` needs to be stored. It seem you are the one not understanding `malloc`.

Comment: @MattS and `char (*pointer)[256];` is a pointer to an `char[256]` array.

Comment: In `append`, you should declare `char (*tmp)[256];` and call `realloc` like this: `tmp = realloc(array->pointer, ...);` Then you check if `tmp == NULL` and handle the error case and if it's not `NULL`, `array->pointer = tmp`;. Also might overflow the pointer if the source string `elem` is longer than 255 characters long, which would lead to undefined behaviour. Use `strncpy(array->pointer[array->used] , elem, sizeof *array->pointer[array->used]); array->pointer[array->used][sizeof(array->pointer[array->used]) - 1] = 0;` instead.

Comment: Pablo you're right about the array, I messed up on the capitalization and was treating it like a sizeof(Array) and not a sizeof(array)... guess there's something to be said here about clear variable names. Re the 256 though... what's the point of stating you have a pointer to a char[256] array if you turn around and malloc/realloc it to whatever size you want?

Comment: @MattS the OP is allocating space for `array->size` arrays of dimension 256. If the OP had `char **pointer`, then the OP must `malloc` with size `array->size * sizeof(char*)` and the for every `i` it would have to do `malloc` again with size 256.

Comment: Thank you @Pablo, it definitely helped me, there must be another error in another module, because I still get `segfault`, but this one went away. I'll investigate in the morning. And thanks @Matt S, yes, clear variable names looks like a good point here.

Comment: Tried using gdb on the OS where it fails?

Comment: yes, it just returns `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.` and number of line in `main`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a need to fix `parse` logic and improvements to `realloc` as per Pablo comments! As mentioned, check for `NULL` when `malloc` or `realloc` returns.

This is a MCVE for your farther improvements:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DEFAULT_SIZE 256

typedef struct {
    char (*pointer)[256];
    int used;
    int size;
} Array;

Array *createArray(int start_size) {
    Array *array = malloc(sizeof(*array));
    array->used = 0;
    array->size = start_size;
    array->pointer = malloc(start_size * sizeof * array->pointer); // 
    return array;
}

void append(Array *array, char* elem) {
    if (array->used >= array->size) {
        // expand table
        array->pointer = realloc(array->pointer, array->size * 2 * sizeof * array->pointer);
        array->size *= 2;
    }
    // append new arg
    strcpy(array->pointer[array->used] , elem); // <-- here
    array->used++;
}


Array *parse(char* command) {
    // split command by space and store each arg in array
    char *args_str;
    Array *args_list = createArray(DEFAULT_SIZE); // expandable array holding arguments

    args_str = strtok(command, " ");

    append(args_list, args_str);

    args_str = strtok(NULL, " ");

    append(args_list, args_str);

    return(args_list);
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = { '1', '2', '3', ' ', '5', '6', '7', ' ', 0 };

    Array *p = parse(str);

    printf("%s\n",p->pointer[0]);
    printf("%s\n",p->pointer[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
123
567
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to quote myself from the comments:

> In append, you should declare char `(*tmp)[256];` and call realloc like this: `tmp = realloc(array->pointer, ...);`.
>
> Then you check if `tmp == NULL` and handle the error case and if it's not `NULL`, `array->pointer = tmp;`.
>   Also might overflow the pointer if the source string elem is longer than 255 characters long,
>   which would lead to undefined behaviour. Use
>
> ```
> strncpy(array->pointer[array->used] , elem, sizeof *array->pointer[array->used]);
> array->pointer[array->used][sizeof(array->pointer[array->used]) - 1] = 0;
> ```
>
> instead.

There is one small problem with your `append` function, it doesn't return
anything. I modifieded it as:

```
Array *parse(char* command) {
    // split command by space and store each arg in array
    char *args_str;
    Array *args_list = createArray(DEFAULT_SIZE); // expandable array holding arguments

    args_str = strtok(command, " ");

    do {
        append(args_list, args_str);
    } while(args_str = strtok(NULL, " "));


    return args_list;
}
```

I took your code and fixed the `parse` function and called it from my `main`
function.

```
int main(void)
{
    Array *array;
    char cmd[] = "ls -alh --color /tmp";

    array = parse(cmd);

    if(array == NULL)
        return 0;

    printf("Array->used: %d, array->size: %d\n", array->used, array->size);
    for(int i = 0; i < array->used; ++i)
        puts(array->pointer[i]);

    free(array->pointer);
    free(array);
}
```

The output I got is:

```
==11553== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11553== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11553== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11553== Command: ./a
==11553== 
Array->used: 4, array->size: 10
ls
-alh
--color
/tmp
==11553== 
==11553== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11553==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11553==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 3,600 bytes allocated
==11553== 
==11553== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==11553== 
==11553== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11553== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The code is working fine, the problem might occur becuase of an undefined
behaviour before the call of `parse`. I've put my test code in here: https://ideone.com/9VYyYH

As you can see on ideone the code also produces the correct result.